# Apache POI can't read Word docx File with rfc2397 embedded PNG images

Tags: apache-poi, mime-types, pandoc

When reading a Word File Apache POI (4.1.2/5.0.0) throws an Exception

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: The specified content type 'image/png;base64' is not compliant with RFC 2616: malformed content type.
```

The File loads fine in Word. It was generated via Pandoc.

[Edit]
RFC 2616 defines "media-type = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )". Parameter is key = value. base64 is of course no key/value. These are defined in [rfc2397](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397)

- How can I suppress this?
- Can I somehow stop Pandoc generating embedded images like this?
- Can apache-poi supportRFC 2397 embedded images?

Testproject : https://github.com/Portree-Kid/testdoc

Bug : https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65320

Comment: You probably need to raise an enhancement request to Apache POI - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI - and upload a small sample document that shows the problem